# Mule connection to Exchange Server

Tags: exchange-server, mule

I need to connect to Exchange Server in Mule but Mule provided OOB IMAP and POP3 are not enabled on our exchange server hence we cannot use them.
Can anyone shed some light here on other alternative ways to connect to exchange server and read the emails.

Answer (score 0):

Mule mail transport implements standard transports, these being **IMAP**, **POP3** and **SMTP**.

If you need anything beside these to access your mail server you should consider writing a custom connector using [devkit](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Anypoint+Connector+DevKit+Guide).

An example of such an approach is the [gmail connector](http://mulesoft.github.io/google-connectors-suite/gmail-connector/mule/gmail-config-with-oauth.html) that leverages google API to retrieve emails rather than the standard mail transport.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the connections from the Internet are handled by IIS on the Exchange Server. The options can be:

1. RPC Over Https. Well known as “Outlook Anywhere”.
2. EWS. Mostly used by MAC Outlook.
3. Activesync – Mobility
4. ECP – management console, configuration via OWA

Thanks,

hope answer the question